# Horizontally center div with variable dimensions within container

Tags: css, center, css-position, centering

I have a div with variable dimensions that I need to dynamically horizontally center within its container. Here is the current structure...

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">Sample</div>
</div>
```

...the "inner" div is the one that will very in height and width based on its contents, and it needs to be horizontally centered (equal space at its left and right sides) within the "outer" div, which may or may not have fixed dimensions (so the "inner" may be within the "outer" div's width, or it may spill out, but always be centered in it). Here are the styles I currently have...

```
.outer {
    width: 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}
.inner {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

...the properties of the "outer" work well to center it within what it's contained in, but the properties of the "inner" have it aligned to the left edge of the "outer" div.

I tried a few options with negative margins and left/right values for the "inner", but they seemed to depend on fixed pixel values whereas I need the dimensions of it to remain variable relative to its content.

The caveat is that the "inner" div needs to be absolute positioned because it has to fix to the bottom edge of the "outer" (hence the "bottom: 0") even when the height of the "outer" is shorter than the inner.

Here's a running example: http://jsfiddle.net/bVC3J/

Anyone have any thoughts on how I can achieve this without using JS? If there is no CSS solution I am open to JS, so you're welcome to suggest that as a last resort. Thanks.

Comment: I dont think it can be done with just CSS, but I'm no expert on CSS, heres your fiddle with some JS http://jsfiddle.net/bVC3J/1/.  I shall keep an eye on this one to see if you get any working CSS solutions.

Comment: @Dampsquid Thanks, that's an ideal JS solution. If all else fails on the CSS front I will go with that. Still holding out for a possible non-JS solution, though. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This might do the job for you: http://jsfiddle.net/fF3A4/1/

```
.outer {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    display:table-cell;
    background:#333;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    text-align:center;
}
.inner {
    width:200px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background:#ccc;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: As I specified in the OP, the "inner" div must not have a fixed width. I have a solution for that scenario already that doesn't require displaying the container as a table cell or automatic left/right margins. However, I need the width of the "inner" div to be variable (no fixed pixel/percent/em values). Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I know you said ity should be variable, and in you live poage it will obviously be variable - but in my example I had to give it a width in order to get it to work. Even though you say it will be variable I'm assuming it will be given a width dynamically?

Comment: No, it will not be given it a fixed width at all. Its width will remain variable and expand/contract relative to the content within it. I only need a solution that will work for that scenario. Thanks.

Comment: I've amended my code above and my jsfiddle link to one which should hopefully accomodate your requirements.

Comment: Sorry, the other requirement was that the "inner" div be absolute positioned so as to maintain its size and horizontal centering within the "outer" container when the width of "outer" dipped below the width of "inner". Thanks.

Comment: I think you'll need to use some JS as well then.

Comment: Agreed, that seems to be the best solution for now. In the meantime I'll hope for a "center" property for absolute positioning about the center (relative to the current top/right/bottom/left) in the next implementation of CSS. Thanks again.